# Can't bring laptop out of hibernation mode

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hibernate

A Windows 7 HP ProBook 6570b laptop is rebooting just after the HP logo appears during the boot process.  This means the laptop reboots about 4 seconds after turning it on.

The laptop had been generating BSOD after what we believe was a virus infection occurred.

If I boot into PMagic from a USB drive, and try to recover some data using File Manager, I get an error saying the device is in hibernation, and cannot be mounted.

I've been told to bring the laptop out of hibernation mode, I need to hold down the power button for 5-20 seconds, however this does not work.

I don't have a HDD caddy or cable to use to connect the laptop HDD to a desktop PC and delete the hibernation file.

I don't have a Windows recovery CD handy, but I may be able to receive one from another office.

How else can I bring the laptop out of hibernation?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [Knoppix](http://knoppix.net/), a Linux boot CD, which allowed me to delete the hibernation file.

To do this, I booted into the Knoppix GUI, opened File Manager, and opened the C drive, which prompted me there was a hibernation file on the drive, and asked me what I wanted to do.